# Neural Network implementation using Pybrain

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I am new to Python and I want to implement a simple Neural Network in Python and I am using Pycharm. I explore which library is used for this purpose and I found that [Pybrain](https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain) can be used. Successfully installed it on my system and configured with Pycharm.

Now I am searching a simple **sample code for Neural Network using Pybrain lib** but did not found a complete code. Also in doc of Pybrain some more explanation is required. Is there any way I can found **detailed documentation of functionalities used in Pybrain**?

As a beginner did I follow the correct path? May be you will feel that this question should not be asked but as a beginner I have to solve it. If anyone can help me in this regard I would be thankful to you.

Comment: have you looked at http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html ?

Comment: documentation for students is clear for Pybrain, but I will suggest you to use tensorflow, has good tutorial and comunity https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/index.html. I think Pybrain is no longer an active project.

Comment: @sb0709 Yes I looked into that link. After that I also saw how to use your own sample data for NN, very next topic to it. But then in chapter 3 it goes on explaining Feed Forward network there I got confused and I thought to get some sample code.